# How to use X509Certificate in bun

Tags: node.js, x509certificate, cryptojs, bun

I need use X509Certificate from node module, but my project is Bun runtime.

```
import { X509Certificate, createDecipheriv, createSign } from 'crypto';
```

when I start the project, it gives me the error:

```
> bun run --hot src/app.ts

1 | (function (entry, fetcher)
    ^
SyntaxError: Export named 'X509Certificate' not found in module 'crypto'.
```

I've searched its official doc : https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/nodejs-apis#node-crypto, they said X509Certificate is not optimized yet.

Comment: did you find solutions ? what version of nodejs are you using ?

Comment: I've adopted https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign
```
const rs = require('jsrsasign');
const x509 = new rs.X509();
  x509.readCertPEM(publicKey);
  const serialNoHex = x509.getSerialNumberHex();
  const serialNo = parseInt(serialNoHex, 16);
```